# codeigniter prints text instead of php code

Tags: php, codeigniter

My default controller is index.php so when i call from it my view its working fine... then i call the following views but it prints text instead of html

```
<?=$this->load->view('header'); ?>
<?=$this->load->view("index/left_side"); ?>
<?=$this->load->view("index/right_side"); ?>
<?=$this->load->view('footer'); ?>
```

i am using WAMP on Windows 7.

Does it have anything to do that i use `<?=` instead of `<?php` ?

**SOLUTION:**
i enabled short tags and asp tags and its working now.

Comment: Make sure your file is saved as .php and not .txt.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default asp_tags and short_open_tag are off on WAMP so try `<?php` not `<?`

Comment: so its safer to use <?php instead of <?

Comment: That would be `short_open_tag`.

Comment: Yes, short_open_tag it's the corect php.ini config for this one, i seen the = and posted asp_tags. Editting

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are referring to the content-type of the reponse or just the output of the function.

But you are using the Load Function wrong. Checkout - [The User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) - The load->view function output the content already. So you would actually use `<?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>` or use the parameters to make it produce a string.

For example :

```
<?php 
    $content =  $this->load->view('header', '', TRUE);
    echo $content;
?>
```

And about the tags. As far as I know it only depends on if your server is configured to support the short tag. (I could be wrong about this).